# How Can I Extract the stringlength higher word in an array?

Tags: php, max, string-length

In the first time, I'm sorry for my disastrous english.
After three days trying to solve this, i give up.

Giving this array:

```
$names = array ( "James Walter Case", "Benjamin Wallace Pinkman", "Billy Elliot Newson" )
```

I have to extract the full name of the higher first stringlength word of each full name.
In this case, considering this condition Benjamin will be the higher name. Once 
this name extracted, I have to print the full name.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: loop the array explode on space, store the count of the first word, sort by or retrieve the highest count

Comment: @Dagon He's obviously a beginner (he spent 3 days on this). I guess you're just speaking chinese to him.

Comment: we all start somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to provide a *handmade* solution.

```
<?php
$maxLength = 0;
$fullName = "";
$parts = array();

foreach($names as $name){
    /* Exploding the name into parts.
     * For instance, "James Walter Case" results in the following array :
     *     array("James", "Walter", "Case") */
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);
    if(strlen($parts[0]) > $maxLength){ // Compare first length to the maximum.
        $maxLength = strlen($parts[0]);
        $fullName = $name;
    }
}

echo "Longest first name belongs to " . $fullName . " (" . $maxLength . " character(s))";
?>
```

Basically, we iterate over the array, split each name into parts (delimited by spaces), and try to find the maximum length among first parts of names (`$parts[0]`). This is basically a maximum search algorithm.

There may be better ways with PHP `array_*` functions, but well, this one gets pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
    $names = array ( "James Walter Case", "Benjamin Wallace Pinkman", "Billy Elliot Newson" );

    if (count($names) > 0)
    {
        $higher_score = 0;

        foreach ($names as $name_key => $name_value) 
        {
            $name_array = explode(" ", $name_value);
            // echo("<br><b>name_array -></b><pre><font FACE='arial' size='-1'>"); print_r($name_array); echo("</font></pre><br>");

            $first_name = $name_array[0];
            // echo "first_name -> ".$first_name."<br>";

            $score = strlen($first_name);
            // echo "score -> ".$score."<br>";

            if ($score > $higher_score)
            {
                $higher_score = $score;
                $winner_key = $name_key;                }
        }
        reset($names);
    }

echo("longest first name is ".$names[$winner_key]." with ".$higher_score." letters.");
```

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you can use `array_map` to get all the lenghts of the first strings, and then get the name based on the key of that value.

```
$names = array ( "James Walter Case", "Benjamin Wallace Pinkman", "Billy Elliot Newson" );

$x = array_map(
    function ($a) {
        $x = explode (" ", $a); // split the string
        return strlen($x[0]); // get the first name
    }
, $names);

$maxs = array_keys($x, max($x)); // get the max values (may have equals)
echo $names[$maxs[0]]; // get the first max
```

-- EDIT

Actually, there is a better way of doing this, considering this case. You can simply order the array by the lenght of the first names, and then get the first key:

```
usort($names, 
    function ($a, $b) {
        $aa = explode(" ", $a); // split full name
        $bb = explode(" ", $b); // split full name
        if (strlen($aa[0]) > strlen($bb[0])){
            return 0; // if a > b, return 0
        } else {
            return 1; // else return 1
        }
    }
);
echo $names[0]; // get top element
```

Comment: What? More lines of code? ;) This solution is elegant as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like..

```
$maxWordLength=0;
$maxWordIndex=null;
foreach ($names as $index=>$name){
   $firstName=first(explode(' ',$name)); 
   if (strlen($firstName)>maxWordLength){
      $maxWordLength=strlen($firstName);
      $maxWordIndex=$index; 
   }
}

if ($maxWordIndex){
   echo $names[$maxWordIndex];
}
```